# What is the preferred way to resolve a component at runtime?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

It is very possible to request some components after the root component has been resolved.
I understand we can use `container.Resolve<ComponentInterface>()` to get the component for this  interface. However, it is neither recommended to reference the container everywhere, nor inject the container to the component. So where can we get this container?

I found something from the document of windsor that it is recommended to use the typed factory facility. However it looks we still need the container or the kernel:

```
var factory = kernel.Resolve<IDummyComponentFactory>();
var component = factory.GetSecondComponent();
```

Where should the kernel come from? 
I even didn't see any benefit by using factory as it looks even more complex.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually services could be injected into constructors and properties.

```
public class Component(IService service)
{
}
```

If something needs to be figured out at runtime, then typed factories become useful:

```
interface IService { }
interface IService<T> : IService { }

interface IServiceFactory
{
    // This creates instance of IService<T>, where T is known at runtime
    IService Create(Type type); 
}
```

The implementation of typed factories usually have to use / have the DI container injected. However, that is an implementation detail decoupled from `Component` class. See Dependency Inversion Principle: https://deviq.com/dependency-inversion-principle/

The basic idea is your own types should, ideally, define a contract for dependent services , and only use the contract to instantiate `IService<T>`. Later if the implementation of the contract needs to be replaced with another, e.g. you decided to use `new`, or DI framework changed, your types will still work without needing to be modified.

Comment: Yes, but how can we get the factory? We still need the container to resolve. Here how can we  get the instance of IServiceFactory?

Comment: Yes, you still need the container. Depends on your scenarios, most DI container supports constructor injection, and injecting the container as a service. For example, if you are coding ASP.NET application, you could add `IServiceFactory` to constructor of one of your controllers. When controller is created, the DI container automatically resolves `IServiceFactory`.